# jQuery datepicker popup's problem (opens again after the date was selected) in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

I met the problem with datepicker in IE 9 (FF and Chrome work fine).

When the user selects some date, popup hides, but after that it opens again. How to fix this?

the code to bind input text with datepicker:

```
$("input[type='datetime']").each(function () {
        var minDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-min"));
        var maxDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-max"));
        var yearrange = $(this).attr("yearrange");

        $(this).datepicker(({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            yearRange: yearrange,
            showOn: "both",
            minDate: minDate,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            maxDate: maxDate,
            buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif")',
            buttonImageOnly: true

        }));
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ;/

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, there has been a bug ([Ticket here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7623)). I downloaded the latest release (1.8.16) and it seems that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Great! They've fixed it. Thanks for the answer.